# mat-select options get hidden on click

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

I am struggling an issue with Mat-Select of Angular Material. I've options in mat-select control, but not showing up.

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
   <mat-label>Roles</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControl]="Toppings" multiple>                  
         <mat-option> Extra Cheese </mat-option>
         <mat-option> No Cheese </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Not showing any mat-options. No error in console. In console debugging on the mat-select, mat-options disappear after below statement execution:

[image]

Please advice, bundle of thanks.

*PS: My project is Angular 10, holding both Kendo UI and Angular Material.*

Comment: why your options have no value?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, it's just test code, even putting [value] isn't making any difference.

Comment: looks like Kendo UI is conflicting, I test you code and it is working fine.